# How to simplify an IF statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

So I have an IF statement in python which essentially looks to change null values in a dataset to an average based off two other columns.

```
def impute_age(cols):
    Age = cols[0]
    Pclass = cols[1]
    Sex = cols[2]

    if pd.isnull(Age):
        if Pclass == 1 and Sex == 0:
            return train.loc[(train["Pclass"] == 1) 
                         & (train["Sex_male"] == 0)]["Age"].mean() 
        if Pclass == 2 and Sex == 0:
            return train.loc[(train["Pclass"] == 2) 
                         & (train["Sex_male"] == 0)]["Age"].mean()
        if Pclass == 3 and Sex == 0:
            return train.loc[(train["Pclass"] == 3) 
                         & (train["Sex_male"] == 0)]["Age"].mean()
        if Pclass == 1 and Sex == 1:
            return train.loc[(train["Pclass"] == 1) 
                         & (train["Sex_male"] == 1)]["Age"].mean()
        if Pclass == 2 and Sex == 1:
            return train.loc[(train["Pclass"] == 2) 
                         & (train["Sex_male"] == 1)]["Age"].mean()
        if Pclass == 3 and Sex == 1:
            return train.loc[(train["Pclass"] == 3) 
                         & (train["Sex_male"] == 1)]["Age"].mean()
    else:
        return Age
```

So here i'm trying to fill in nans using the average age of male/females in certain passenger classes. I feel like there would be a much better way of writing this, especially if I was to come across a much bigger dataset.
For reference the `train` df is the main df with all of the data. For some reason I couldn't get this code to work with a subset of train passed through using the `cols` argument.

The question here is essentially: how can I write this in a much simpler way & is there a way I could write this IF statement if my dataset was MUCH larger?

Comment: why do you need any of those if's? just use the variables

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears to me that all you need to do is parameterize your inner `if`:

```
if pd.isnull(Age):
    return train.loc[(train["Pclass"] == Pclass) 
                   & (train["Sex_male"] == Sex)]["Age"].mean()
```

Comment: works perfectly. Could you explain the logic behind this?

Comment: This is simple variable usage.  I'll tell you what ... work through a few more tutorials or class materials with variables that change through a program, where a line of code is executed more than once.  Also insert useful `print` statements to trace the execution.  See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.
If you're still confused after that, post another comment or a new question.  Tag me in a comment, and I'll come back to explain ... but you'll learn more deeply if you investigate by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
PCLASS_VALUES = [
[],
]

SEX_VALUES = [
[],
]

return train.loc[(train["Pclass"] == PCLASS_VALUES[Pclass][Sex]) & (train["Sex_male"] == SEX_VALUES[Pclass][Sex])]["Age"].mean()
```